# Change drag cursor in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, drag-and-drop

I have to create a listview with draggable items. I found a solution in codeproject

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17266/Drag-and-Drop-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView?fid=378031&fr=51&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed#xx0xx

That's the best code found over net. Now I need to change the drag cursoe to sizeAll.

Is there any ways to change the default dragging cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the program you linked to.

To achieve what you want add this in `ListViewDragDropManager.cs`'s `#region Hook Events` region:

```
this.listView.GiveFeedback += listView_GiveFeedback;
```

And then add this to the `#region Event Handling Methods` part:

```
private void listView_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
    {
        e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
        Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.SizeAll);
    }
    else
        e.UseDefaultCursors = true;

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe in the `#region Unhook Events` part:

```
this.listView.GiveFeedback -= listView_GiveFeedback;
```